# I keep receiving a Object Reference not set to an instance of an object error on compilation after installing Template10 build 1.1.7

Tags: xaml, msbuild, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

Every time I try and compile my app (Petrolhead - source code at https://github.com/SupernovaApps/Petrolhead), after upgrading to Template10 1.1.7, I get the following error:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(350,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does anyone know what this means, and what I can do about it?

(I'd appreciate if someone could download the source for my app, and see if they receive the same error. I'm currently testing the UWP client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I was trying to create a Tapped event for an item inside a GridView, instead of using ItemClick, which UWP didn't seem too happy about.

Comment: ItemClicked fires when you click an item. Tapped fires when you click the GridView.

Comment: It gets "twitchy" whenever there's a mismach!  In my case i accidently had a {Binding} in the `Click` property (instead of `Command`) and it took me hours disabling all my XAML until i tracked it down!